# Obfuscar not work in azure-devops pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, obfuscation

I tried obfuscation of my c# dll with 'Obfuscar' with following variables

```
<Var name="InPath" valur="."/>
<Var name="OutPath" value="..\Obfuscated" />
<Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="true" />
<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" /> 
<Module file="*.dll" />
```

I want to keep public method to using this dll in other project.

and those variables are well work on my PC.

I can see the obfuscated private methods through the dotPeek.

So, I pushed my solution to repository of Azure-DevOps with pipelines to publishing artifacts of build result

But, when I download the published dll. It's not obfuscated!!

To checking the process, I tried to obfuscation also public method like follow

```
<Var name="InPath" valur="."/>
<Var name="OutPath" value="..\Obfuscated" />
<Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" /> 
<Module file="*.dll" />
```

It is well work!! I got fully obfuscated dll

Problem is I can't using this fully obfuscated dll in the other project......because of obfuscated public method.

Summary:

- What I want?

---

-> dll obfuscated only private methods through the azure-devops pipeline

---

-> Because I want to using it in the other project

---

- What I used?

---

-> 'Obfuscar' package on Visual studio

---

-> Variables: KeepPublicApi = true, HidePrivateApi = true

---

- Situation

---

-> Well work on local PC

---

-> Not work on azure-devops pipeline
- Variables: KeepPublicApi = true, HidePrivateApi = true   -> not obfuscated

```
   - Variables: KeepPublicApi = false, HidePrivateApi = true   -\> well obfuscated
```

Please help me to get obfuscated dll through the azure-devops pipeline which can be usable in the other project

It is ok to suggest any other tools can be used in the azure-devops pipeline

Comment: Another option would be using Nuke.Build with azure pipelines, where you can use Obfuscar global tool.